# MySQL create Datetime field from Timestamp field

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a simple problem for which I found a solution in early testing but cannot replicate now that I need to do it for real.

We are moving our news system from CuteNews to our self-built MySQL system. All the news has been imported into the database but the date field is Timestamp. I have created a new field (created_date) and want to populate this from the Timestamp in the date field.

As I said, I did do this previously in an early trial run and was convinced that the query I used, via PhpMyAdmin was along the lines of `UPDATE News set created_date=UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)`. This is probably slightly wrong as I am at work and posting from my phone but it was along those lines.

No errors were returned but all 'created_date' fields were populated as `0000-00-00 00:00` not with the date taken from the Timestamp in the date field.

I know it is simple and know the answer will be obvious when I see it but any pointers would be gratefully appreciated!

Steve.

EDIT: reading back through I realised a bit of what I posted may be misleading. In my original trial run using the update query put the correct DateTime in the field based on the corresponding Timestamp field. It is only this time that it shows 0000-00-00 00:00.

Ps. Thanks for the format tidy-up. It's a bit awkward on a phone!

Comment: What is the field TYPE of `created_date` ?

Comment: It looks as though MySQL thinks that the data in your _date_ columns is invalid, so it's converting them to `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. Are you sure that they are valid? I had a quick look in the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) on date data types and there's some discussion in the comments there on adding `INTERVAL 0 DAY` to invalid dates to automagically make them valid - maybe something to try. I **do** hope that you are experimenting with a `SELECT` query before trying things with an `UPDATE` :-)

Comment: created_date is a DateTime field.

Comment: I am trying directly with UPDATE but with a smaller version of the table on my own local server, so there is no risk if breaking the real one! Not seen the INTERVAL 0 DAY trick before but do not think it is down to invalid data as it worked fine with the same data in a test a few months back.

Comment: When you use `SET timestampcolumn = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datecolumn)` you will get a data truncation error. It's true, that timestamp columns are stored as integers internally, but you can't assign integers directly. Otherwise MySQL couldn't decide if '20130611' is a date or an integer. Just do `SET timestampcolumn = datecolumn` and you'll be fine. The reason you might get `0000-00-00 00:00:00` might be, that the timestamp data type has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-09 03:14:07' UTC?

Answer (score 0):

I knew I was nearly there!! It was not `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` but `FROM_UNIXTIME` I was after.

```
UPDATE news SET created_date = FROM_UNIXTIME(date)
```

Thanks for the help.

Steve